# What if you get an answer to an old unanswered question, and you cannot anymore "judge" if it's "acceptable"?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693296/howto-custom-field-in-lift-record-squeryl) "ages" ago (in April 2011). It now received an answer for the first time. Unfortunately, I cannot judge anymore if the answer is any good, since I haven't used that language/API combination for many years.

I don't want to just ignore the answer, but I don't really want to spend days re-learning the language+APIs just to decide if the answer is right, just so I can forget all about it again.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wait. If it's really a good answer, getting a lot of upvotes from the community (i.e. people who still have the right knowledge), you could consider accepting it as it would be 'likely' to have solved your problem back then. If you decide to re-use the language/API again in the future, and discover that it doesn't work for you, you can always unaccept.

Other than that, accepting an answer is *never* required. So there's no harm in just not accepting it, how good it may be.